# In flutter, how would I save the TextBox input from generated textboxes?

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-layout

Below is my full code, the only thing you need to do to run it is adding "http: any" to dependencies in pubspec.yaml.

What the code does is grab JSON input from source, and for each entry in the json feed create a card.  Now for each question, I want the user to provide an answer, so when I add the button to the bottom, it brings up a popup box showing the answers (which I'll later post back to my server).
It would look something like:

> Q1: "three"
>
> Q2: "thirty"
>
> Q3: "Some movie character"
>
> Q4: "Walter White"

(I'll do the validation to my answers later)

My json is posted below the code.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


Future<List<Question>> fetchQuestions(http.Client client) async {
  final response =
      await client.get('https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/a5885973-7f02-11ea-b97d-097037d3b153');

  // Use the compute function to run parsePhotos in a separate isolate
  return compute(parseQuestion, response.body);
}

// A function that will convert a response body into a List<Photo>
List<Question> parseQuestion(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  return parsed.map<Question>((json) => Question.fromJson(json)).toList();
}

class Question {
  final int id;
  final String question;
  final String answer;

  Question({this.id, this.question, this.answer});

  factory Question.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Question(
      id: json['id'] as int,
      question: json['question'] as String,
      answer: json['answer'] as String
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appTitle = 'Isolate Demo';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
    );
  }
}

 class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<Question>>(
          future: fetchQuestions(http.Client()),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

            return snapshot.hasData
                ? QuestionList(questions: snapshot.data)
                : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          },
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(1.0, 10.0, 1.0, 10.0),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class QuestionList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Question> questions;

  QuestionList({Key key, this.questions}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: questions.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(
                  height: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1.fontSize * 1.1 +
                      200.0,
                ),
                color: Colors.blueGrey,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Card(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ListTile(

                        title: Text(questions[index].id.toString()),
                        subtitle: Text(questions[index].question),
                      ),
                      new TextFormField(
                      decoration: new InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Answer Question",
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                          borderSide: new BorderSide(
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      validator: (val) {
                        if(val.length==0) {
                          return "Type your answer here";
                        }else{
                          return null;
                        }
                      },
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      style: new TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: "Poppins",
                      ),
                    ),

                        /*
                        // make buttons use the appropriate styles for cards
                        ButtonBar(
                          children: <Widget>[                         
                            RaisedButton(
                              color: Colors.lightBlue,
                              hoverColor: Colors.blue,
                              child: const Text('Open'),
                              onPressed: () {/* ... */},
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                     */
                    ],
                  ),
                )),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}



[
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "question" : "what is one plus two",
        "answer": "three"
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "question" :  "what is five times 6",
        "answer": "thirty"
    },
    {
        "id" : 3,
        "question" : "Who said show me the money",
        "answer": "Cuba Gooding Jnr"
    },
    {
        "id" : 4,
        "question" : "who said I am the danger",
        "answer": "Walter White"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider attaching a `TextEditingController` to the `TextFormField` through the `controller` property. You can access the text currently in the TextField using the controller's `text` field.

Comment: Ok, that seems to make sense, currently though, my form is built as a stateless widget, do I need to change it to be stateful, so I can dispose of the widget?  And how do I bind the answer to the question id that I get from json?

Comment: You may use a StatefulWidget only if you want your UI to change based on given answers. Consider wrapping your fields in a Form, so you can save all the fields by calling the save() method of the form's state. You then can configure each field's behaviour when the form is saved through the onSaved property, specifically setting the answer property of the appropriate Question instance.

Form docs:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Form-class.html

FormState docs:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FormState-class.html